# Should we care about spoilers?

Tags: discussion

Should we, in asking and answering our questions, be concerned about avoiding spoiling mythological narratives for other people?

Many other fiction-based SE sites have policies on spoilers, including [SF&F](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/15276), [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers), [Anime](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers), and [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoilers). What about this site?

(This meta post is prompted by the presumably tongue-in-cheek comments on [this question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/155/33).)

Comment: My take: never use spoiler formatting in questions (no point; check the tags before opening a question if you really care). Also never use spoiler formatting in answers unless the asker explicitly requests it (mythological narratives aren't really about plot twists in the way that some conventional fiction is; knowing that Fenrir kills Odin during Ragnarok doesn't "ruin" the Eddas).

Comment: I agree with @senshin. The point of mythology is that it's old, so having spoilers is basically nonsensical.

Comment: I have honestly never thought that spoilers is a thing in myths.

Comment: Haha, the comments were indeed tongue in cheek. I was writing the question as I would for SF&F, and the fact that I instinctively thought to put spoilers in (OMG SOMEONE DIED) amused me :P

Comment: It would also get tiresome pretty quickly. A LOT of people die in mythology.. .

Answer (score 9):

I don't think that this site requires spoilers. As others have said, the myths are largely centuries old, and therefore, spoiling is pretty unavoidable.

(The comments you pointed to were indeed tongue-in-cheek - I started writed the question, and instinctively thought of spoiler-marking "beheading" as I would for a newer story.)

The one exception might be potential questions about modern adaptations of a myth that change an element of the myth (and this is completely hypothetical, I've no idea if it would ever happen). If, for example, there is a TV or book series doing a modern adaptation of a set of myths, and kills off a character unexpectedly, and someone wants to ask a question about how this relates to the original myth, I would courtesy-spoiler the new death. However, that's pretty much the only situation I can imagine anything spoilerific being mentioned here.